# browse files over specific number of pages

Tags: python, google-chrome, browser

I a wondering if there is a way of retrieving search results containing only files at or above a certain number of pages.

I am currently using the Chrome browser and trying to extract pdf files
using the filetype filter:

```
filetype:pdf
```

and I would like to see only files of 30 pages or more.

So far I have tried to download files first and then using Python to check number of pages. Is there an advanced google search filter option do accomplish this (maybe indirectly by controlling file size?), or perhaps another browser which allows this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I a wondering if there is a way of retrieving search results*
>   *containing only files at or above a certain number of pages.*

**No**, I'm afraid there's no way to do that.
Search engines do not provide operators to search for documents with a `X` number of pages. Searching by **file size** is **unreliable** since **a `2` page `pdf` can have a `30 Mb` and another one with `20` pages just `1Mb`**. Size varies according to embedded media, compression, among other factors.

Answer (score -1):

For this, you need to use [Googles Advances Search Feature.](https://www.google.com/advanced_search?q=)
This allows you to build searches with greater granularity and also see the proper syntax for compiling that search. 
To more precicely answer your question in order to search PDF's by number of pages, when you do your google search, format the search as follows:

`"Your search Criteria" filetype:pdf 0..30`

Where the minimum number of pages is the O and the max number of pages is the 30.
If you want a minimum of 30 with no maximum set you can leave the max blank like this:

`"Your search Criteria" filetype:pdf 30..`

Once you have these search results you can use BeautifulSoup, scrapy, etc. to grab a list of links and iterate over them to download all of the PDF's

Comment: ***"Put two full stops between the numbers and add a unit of measurement: 10..35 kg, £300..£500, 2010..2011"***  - It has nothing to do with page numbers. Have you tried it yourself?! - https://www.google.com/advanced_search?q=&hl=en

Comment: Yes your correct that it does not directly correlate to the page numbers.  The verbose filer criteria posed by this is "find all results containing 'your search criteria' of filetype: PDF and Find pages with numbers ranging from x to y" so it will return any pages that meet those criteria, and that caveat is warranted, but this method does return the desired result in most situations because the pages contain the page numbers far more often than they contain arbitrary numbers.